# regex wont work

Tags: java, regex

maybe someone can help me with a regular expression. This one wont work:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String pattern = "(?i).*a[\\s-\\.]?nton.*";
    String text = "a-nton vom 27.2.2012";
    if (pattern.matches(text)){
        System.out.println("FOUND");
    }else{
        System.out.println("NOT FOUND");
    }
}
```

The regex should be true if text contains one of these words:

> a-nton OR 
>   a nton OR 
>   anton

before and after this word can be any text

But the pattern above will be "NOT FOUND"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `if (pattern.matches(text)) {` to `if (text.matches(pattern)) {`.

The matches method checks in the String invoked on for the pattern passes to the method, so invoke it on text and pass it pattern. You may also want to look at the `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes if you want more advanced regex in the future.

See the javadoc on the [matches(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) method:

> Parameters: regex - the regular expression to which this string is to
>   be matched

Comment: Also, the character class should be `[\\s.-]`. I'm surprised that trying to build a range between `\s` and `.` doesn't throw a `PatternSyntaxException`...

Comment: Thanks! But now i get a  java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character range near index 13
(?i).*a[\\s-\\.]?nton.*